# Is there anything wrong with this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, american-english, parentheses

I'm focused on the punctuation. If anybody can help point out if there are any errors, I'd appreciate it.

> The two characters in the band are
>   James (left—who I worked with
>   previously for his old group, Typhoon
>   Loco) and DJ Siphon (aka
>   “Siphonator”—right). Below are
>   reference photos given to me by the
>   guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about those em-dashes separating the stage-directions (or whatever you would call them) from the rest of the parentheticals.   Why don't you re-write it to dodge the issue:

> The two characters in the band are
>   James (left) with whom I worked
>   previously in Typhoon
>   Loco, his old group, and DJ Siphon (right), aka
>   “Siphonator”.

Of course, some might say the comma after "group" should be elevated to a semi-colon...